# Mail Sending in TCPDF

Tags: email, tcpdf

I have created a PDF using tcpdf function, then i wants to send it to a mail as attachment. i have used following coding at end of the creation of PDF. But it working in some server, but not working in some other servers

```
$from = "manikandan@niral.us";
        $subject = "test";
        $message = $_REQUEST['msg'];


        // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
        $separator = md5(time());

        // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
        $eol = PHP_EOL;
         // $eol = "\r\n";
        // attachment name
        $filename = "Yourinvices.pdf";

        // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
        $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output('Patient'.$invnumserial.'.pdf', 'S');
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc)); 

        // encode data (multipart mandatory)
        $headers = "From: ".$from.$eol;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Enconding: 7bit".$eol;
        $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

        // message
        $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charsrt=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
        $headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

        // attachment
        $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
        //$headers .= "Content-Type: application/zip; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= "--".$separator."--";

        // send message
       if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
       {

         Redirect("../../patient_invoicelist.php?msg=1");   
      }

       else Redirect("../../patient_invoicelist.php?msg=2");
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i didnt get any error message, when i execute this , else statement is executed. How can i get the error message, please help me

Comment: Just remove @ before you call the mail function.

Comment: I tried that also, but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHPMailer` to send `Emails with Attachments`. It will be very easy to send emails with attachments using this library.
Download `PHPMailer` library from this link. You will also find examples to use this class.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/

```
$mail->SetFrom('noreply@test.com', 'test');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->AddAttachment($Pdf_path_here);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($to, "");

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
   echo "sent";
} 
else 
{
   echo "error";
}
```

Comment: if i use this Means following error occurs ,Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in /home/content/43/9948643/html/anntool/tcpdf/examples/Phpmailer/examples/test_mail_basic.php on line 14

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /home/content/43/9948643/html/anntool/tcpdf/examples/Phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1471

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /home/content/43/9948643/html/anntool/tcpdf/examples/Phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1475

Comment: eregi_replace() is deprecated in /home/content/43/9948643/html/anntool/tcpdf/examples/Phpmailer/examples/test_mail_basic.php on line 14 what can i do for this error, Error in the line $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

Comment: i am using this version PHP 5.4

Comment: Instead of using that eregi_function, use this $body = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 2 in /home/content/43/9948643/html/anntool/tcpdf/examples/Phpmailer/examples/test_mail_basic.php on line 14 , Now i got this error

Comment: I gave an example in my answer, check it

Comment: do i need to change any configuration in PHP mailer function ?

Comment: still mail is is not sent? can u show me a simple example with full detailed coding? it would be very helpfull for me